# Cronjob and PHPmailer not working as expected

Tags: php, email, cron, phpmailer

I have two cron jobs

```
0 8 * * *   /usr/bin/php /var/www/Apps/Appsname/Extract.php
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/Apps/Appsname/weeklybusinessemail.php
```

The extract cronjob works perfectly fine.

The weeklybusinessemail.php does not.

It has a phpmailer script with attachments in it.

When I run weeklybusinessemail.php via the url it works and sends an email,  yet via the crontab it does not!
All names match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: cron syntax looks fine, please provide weeklybusinessemail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without more debug info, but a common problem when running cron tasks is the working directory location. If you're expecting your attachments to be in the folder with the script and refer to them using relative paths like `filename.txt`, that path is not relative to the script, but the cron process' working dir, which could be anywhere. It works when you run it from the web because your web server changes directory to the virtual host's root directory before running your script, so relative paths will work.

Try either using absolute paths for your file attachments (e.g. using `__DIR__.'/filename.txt'`), or change directory before running your cron task:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /var/www/Apps/Appsname && /usr/bin/php /var/www/Apps/Appsname/weeklybusinessemail.php
```

Comment: This worked. I changed the attached csv file paths and gave them the full location of the file. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`> /dev/null` redirects standard output.
`2>&1` redirects standard error (2) to standard output (1)

try :

```
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/Apps/Appsname/weeklybusinessemail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

if application is mvc:

```
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/Apps/Appsname/index.php controller_folder/controller_class_name > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question asked!